# (Facebook C# SDK) Retrieve friends email and birthday

Tags: facebook-c#-sdk

How can I retrieve my friends email-addresses? I can get a list of all my friends but only their name and id. I guess I've got to add some Perms but I don't really know how. Some code examples?

The same goes for the birthday question.

Thanks!

// Nicke

Answer (score 1):

There is no way for apps to obtain email addresses for a user's friends. See the documentation https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/login/email-permissions/

Answer (score 0):

You cannot get your friends email addresses without their express permission. They must authorise your application with the "email" permission.

See the [Facebook Authentication Permissions page](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/permissions/) for more details. Here you will see "not available" in the "friends permission" column for the email permission.

As for birthdays, you need the "friends_birthday" permission.

The easiest way to add permissions is to use the [JavaScript library](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/) for authentication

Answer (score 0):

You just use the **[permissions](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/login/)** you want in the button as an attribute, if you want the `email` just use

```
<fb:login-button perms="email"></fb:login>
```

The Basic Access is always added.

You can try yourself using the [**Facebook Read Eval Log Loop**](http://www.fbrell.com/xfbml/fb%3alogin-button-perms)